# MS Access Upgrade to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ms-access, upsizing

I have developed an MS Access 2007 database with forms that works fine in
access, but when I upsize the back end to SQL Server, I completely lose
functionality on a sub-form.  Has anyone else run in to this problem?  Is
there a work around?

Comment: are you talking about the GUI forms that you can build in Access? I don't think SQL Server has the same functionality... you'd have to build your own interface... something like a WinForm in Visual Studio, and integrate the back end with SQL Server.

Comment: What do you mean by "completely lose functionality"?

Comment: Rocketc, he clearly means that he has moved from using an Access database to store the tables to using SQL Server to store the tables.  But keeping the queries, forms, reports, macros and VBA code within Access.

Comment: Do all your data tables have primary keys and timestamp fields in them? If not, that will cause problems in bound forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, after making all of the suggested changes, it turns out that the problematic sub-form was corrupt.  I rebuilt the project from scratch in Access 2007 and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just in the middle of a similar project and have encountered something similar. For me the problem was with datetime fields.

Please check that your forms data/recordset has a datetime field... if it does try changing it to a datetime2 (this seemed to fix it for me in 90% of cases), though you'll probably have to re-import/re-run the ssma app to get the dates imported as datatime2.

@David-w-fenton afaik when you link a table in access it insists on you choosing some field(s) as primary keys

Comment: It may be that linking the table forces you to choose a PK, but if it's not really a defined PK, the communication between Access/Jet/ACE/ODBC and your server will be much less efficient.

Comment: very true, SIDE NOTE: I've just tested it and you can actually cancel when choosing a primary key during the table linking in access and it doesnt cancel the link but the choice of primary key.